# Export List of Pandas Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to export a  list of pandas dataframes to excel

```
list_of_df_to_dump = [df1,df2,...,df100]
list_of_tab_names = ['df1','df2',...,'df100']

writer = ExcelWriter(excel_name + '.xlsx')
for i,j in list_of_df_to_dump,list_of_tab_names:
     i.to_excel(writer,j,index = False)
writer.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Any ideas as to how this could be fixed or alternative methods to accomplish the same thing? I do not know how long the list will be so doing it manually

Comment: Your for statement is not correct.  Try: `for i,j in zip(list_of_df_to_dump,list_of_tab_names):`

Comment: Weird. Making up some data to test your code I get a ValueError as I expected. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `zip` to iterate through pairs of items from two lists like that. Try the following fix:

```
list_of_df_to_dump = [df1,df2,...,df100]
list_of_tab_names = ['df1','df2',...,'df100']

writer = ExcelWriter(excel_name + '.xlsx')
for df, tab_name in zip(list_of_df_to_dump, list_of_tab_names):
     df.to_excel(writer, tab_name, index=False)
writer.save()
```